# How to dispaly current value CheckTree in Label widget using Snack TUI

Tags: python

I use snack package from newt distr and I am trying to get current selected value of CheckTree and put it in Label widgit when press Arrow Up/Down. Unfortunately I do not find any answers and examples of it.

I was able only get current value and put it in Label widget then press F12 button in cycle while.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    # Demo program to show use of python-newt module

    from snack import *

    screen = SnackScreen()
    screen.drawRootText(2, 1, "Test program fpr TreeList")


    bb = ButtonBar(screen, (("Ok", "ok"), ("Cancel", "cancel")))

    ct = CheckboxTree(height = 5, scroll = 1)
    ct.append("Colors")
    ct.addItem("Red", (0, snackArgs['append']))
    ct.addItem("Yellow", (0, snackArgs['append']))
    ct.addItem("Blue", (0, snackArgs['append']))
    ct.append("Flavors")
    ct.append("Numbers")
    ct.addItem("1", (2, snackArgs['append']))
    ct.addItem("2", (2, snackArgs['append']))
    ct.addItem("3", (2, snackArgs['append']))
    ct.append("Names")
    ct.append("Months")
    ct.append("Events")
    grid = None
    grid = Grid(2,3)
    grid.setField(ct, 0,0, padding=(1, 0, 0, 0))
    description = Label("--- Test ---")
    grid.setField(description, 1,0, padding=(1, 0, 0, 1))

    g = GridForm(screen, "My Test", 1, 4)
    g.add(grid, 0, 2)
    g.add(bb, 0, 3, growx = 1)

    while 1:
        description.setText(ct.getCurrent())
        result = g.run()

    screen.finish()
    print result
```

Unfortunatelly  I do not find any tutorial for python module, may be someone have more expirience for such task?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my problem by call setCallback function.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, types, os.path
import signal

from atk import Text
from snack import *

class ui:

    def putDescription(self):
        self.description.setText(self.desc[self.ct.getCurrent()])

    def init(self):
        # snack
        self.screen = SnackScreen()

        #self.screen.popHelpLine()
        self.config = None
        self.toplevel = GridForm(self.screen, "Treechekbox", 2, 6)

        self.desc = {}

        self.ct = CheckboxTree(height = 5, scroll = 1)

        self.desc['cl'] = "begin"
        self.desc['r'] = "Short description"
        self.desc['y'] = "Long long long description ------------------------"
        self.desc['b'] = "Short description"

        self.ct.append("Colors",item="cl", selected=1 )
        self.ct.addItem("Red", (0, snackArgs['append']), item="r", selected=1)
        self.ct.addItem("Yellow", (0, snackArgs['append']), item="y", selected=1)
        self.ct.addItem("Blue", (0, snackArgs['append']), item="b", selected=1)

        grid = None
        grid = Grid(2,3)
        grid.setField(self.ct, 0, 0, padding=(1, 0, 0, 0), anchorLeft=1, anchorTop=1)

        self.description = Textbox(width=20, height=5, text="", scroll=1, wrap=1)
        self.description.setText("Debug mmessage")
        grid.setField(self.description, 1, 0, padding=(1, 0, 0, 0), anchorLeft=1, anchorTop=1)

        self.ct.setCallback(self.putDescription)
        self.toplevel.add(grid, 0, 0, padding=(0, 0, 0, 1), growx=1)

        self.toplevel.bb = ButtonBar(self.screen,((("OK"), "ok"),(("Cancel"), "cancel")))
        self.toplevel.add(self.toplevel.bb, 0, 3, growx=1)

    def finish(self):
        self.screen.finish()

    def main(self):
        while 1:
            res = self.toplevel.runPopup()
            str = self.toplevel.bb.buttonPressed(res)
            self.screen.popWindow()

            if str == 'ok':
                return True
            elif str == 'cancel':
                return False

    def run(self):
        self.init()
        res = self.main()
        self.finish()
        return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal (signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

iui = ui()
iui.run()
```

Comment: if you have another problem then create another post

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)